# how to make g-wan work with (mybb,wordpress,...) rewrite rule

Tags: url-rewriting, g-wan

i'am new to **g-wan** and i'am so confused

i want to know how to make mybb and wordpress and any php script work with g-wan

and if there are any tool to convert apache htaccess to g-wan

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make mybb and wordpress and any php script work with g-wan

The Web servers that support PHP are running PHP through fastCGI and require Apache-like configuration files.

G-WAN was designed with other constraints in mind (zero-configuration, low-latency, etc.) and this is why it has been designed differently - to serve other needs.

> any tool to convert apache htaccess to g-wan

A G-WAN handler could easily enforce htaccess policies, with an even higher level of control since it would be done programmatically (therefore being able to take dynamic parameters into account like server load, sophisticated client IP address filters, etc.).

This question illustrates how G-WAN (an app. server like GlassFish, Tuxedo or Tomcat) was rather designed as a tool for programmers while Web servers like Apache are mainly designed to serve the needs of Webmasters.

Answer (score 3):

G-WAN is not that wide spread at this point and there's no current existing community to share code and exchange information and help. I've looked at trying to use MyBB, SMF, XenForo and some other frameworks and apps for PHP and they always run into a few problems. You have to remember that even though it seems that those apps run universally on Apache/nginx and maybe others, they've been written on those platforms, tested on those platforms, and have compatibility checks to ensure they work on those major platforms. PHP isn't a language that just works out of the box regardless of what is running it.

To answer your question more directly, there are no existing tools to accomplish what you are asking and it's up to you or other developers to do it and hopefully share with others so the G-WAN community can grow.

What you may find interesting, however, is G-WAN is the most flexible web and applications server available and you can mix and match all of the supported languages and not be stuck to just one language or framework. I find this feature to be one of the most rewarding as it opens you up to develop new websites and web applications from scratch with an assortment of programmers from various backgrounds and knowledge of languages and make it all work together with an HTML/Javascript/CSS front-end.

The fun here lies in the challenge of modifying those major scripts to work with G-WAN and watch how much faster they can fly on G-WAN.